# Convert PHP array into JSON object for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, materialize

I am using the [MaterializeCSS autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) and would like to use one of my PHP arrays to output all of the possible options into a form. Please see below for the current code.

```
  const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: {
      "Test1": null,
      "Test2": null,
      "Test3": null
    },
  });
```

I would very much like to use a simple $keysArray in order to input the Test1, Test2, Test3 options etc. However, I understand from the MaterializeCSS page that the autocomplete is using an object and not an array. As such, I have attempted to convert my $keysArray into an object using various different methods:

```
  <?php
  $keysArray = array (
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
  );
  ?>

  var tempArray = <?php echo json_decode(json_encode($keysArray)); ?>; // Doesn't work
  var tempArray = <?php echo json_decode(json_encode($keysArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)); ?>; // Also doesn't work

  const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: tempArray;
  });
```

None of the tempArray's work. I would very much appreciate if anyone can help me sort out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are decoding it back into an array as soon as it is encoded.

Comment: remove json_decode call

Comment: maybe this would work $keysObject= (object) $keysArray;

Comment: Not sure why I can't make it work using the Javascript approach but it's easy enough when using Jquery. https://jsfiddle.net/9umcre8f/ Is that something you could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your array into similar key-value structure:

```
  $keysArray = array(
    "Test1" => null,
    "Test2" => null,
    "Test3" => null,
  );
  echo json_encode($keysArray); // {"Test1":null,"Test2":null,"Test3":null}
```

It can be converted with:

```
$array = array('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');
$keysArray = array_combine($array, array_fill(0, count($array), null));
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but even when I convert to a key-value structure it still doesn't work. I am starting to think something else entirely is causing the issue?

Comment: `Doesn't work` is useless sentence. As you can see, correct array structure json_encoded into correct json. So you have an issue somethere also, may be.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out that I had to put a comma after "data: tempArray" instead of semicolon. That is what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are decoding it back into an array as soon as it is encoded.  Remove `json_decode`.

```
  <?php
  $keysArray = array (
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
  );
  ?>

  var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($keysArray); ?>;

  const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: tempArray;
  });
```

Comment: There seems to be general agreement that the decode should be removed! However, this doesn't help for some reason. I used the decode and encode together because of the following link: https://thewebtier.com/php/convert-array-object-php/ - but maybe it is something else entirely that is going wrong?

Comment: @ChartProblems I think you're confused about arrays and objects in PHP vs JavaScript, two separate languages. That article is talking about converting the array to a PHP object but you want an object to use in JavaScript. `json_encode` encodes a PHP array or object into JavaScript Object Notation which can be used directly in JavaScript code as a JavaScript object. PHP runs on the server whereas JavaScript is executed when the browser downloads it and renders the page.

Comment: @ChartProblems What does the output look like? View the page's source and look at the JS code. The output of the PHP code will be within the JS code. In this case the output should just be JSON.